# tag synonym reminder -> reminders

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I think [reminder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reminder) should be a synonym of [reminders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reminders) - I didn't find the question mine got duped to because it actually doesn't come up on a search of 'share reminder' - but does on 'share reminders'.  I am not completely sure if this would actually improve that searching, but regardless I think it will help in general.

Comment: One note: there is a chat room; [Better tags for Ask Different](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2510/better-tags-for-ask-different) for this. That would be a better place to discuss tags.

Answer (score 1):

There is no [reminder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reminder) tag on the main site. The source question uses [reminders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reminders), and the title uses the word 'reminders' in the title as well. This actually sounds like a bad search heuristic more than anything.

Don't fret about having your question closed :).